# What is causing my muscles to itch?

Tags: muscle-soreness

For as long as I can remember, I've had an intermittent sensation in some of my back muscles I can only describe as itching. As I write this my left shoulder blade is itching. That is a very common place for me, more so than the right. When I flex it I feel very mild pain, the type you get after exercise. Scratching it does not relieve the sensation.

I've been working out with a personal trainer for about a year now. I had assumed that the itchiness was related to me being unfit and possibly having bad posture and that it would disappear by itself as my fitness increased, but it's still there.

What's causing this muscular itchiness and is there a simple way to get rid of it?

Comment: make an appoint with a doctor